# bootstrap modal not working at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked hundred of times before and I've been through them but those couldn't fix my case :s

This is my code so far

```
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

and inside body I have this:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I use some other libraries on the head section because I need them for Google Map maybe, I tried to remove those but still didn't trigger the Modal view.

Comment: Please specify what the problem is for this example.

Comment: The problem is when i click the button modal view doesnt come it just being added #modal like this search.php#modal on the URL

Comment: i think you forgot to add the javascript piece of code ( $("#MyModal").modal(); ). See my answer. It may help you.

Comment: In Bootstrap v4.5 and up, you should use `bootstrap.bundle.js` instead of `bootstrap.js` to have popper functionality.

Comment: add ``data-target=".modal"`` where the anchor tag is.

Answer (score 180):

Check the version of bootstrap. Take attention that in bootstrap 5 changed data-toggle to data-**bs**-toggle and data-target to data-**bs**-target

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. It seems the bootstrap team has not updated their own site with the new syntax. Note: the Close button and X buttons won't work either until you change data-dismiss to data-bs-dismiss.

Comment: bingo - great catch.  the highly indexed bootstrap docs still reflect v4!  beware.

Comment: It's kinda terrible that the v4 docs still show v4 as being the latest version.

Comment: nice one, when i went to the bootstrap site it seemed to default to the v4 documentation still

Answer (score 33):

have you used the cdn or file `popper.js` 
If you not include `popper.js` file you wont be able to see your modal windows
check the below cdn and put below `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` as follows below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now it will work 100% if not I have another solution
 copy the below code and check it

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this line to Javascript file

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MyModal").modal();
  });
```

Comment: it returns $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: You have to give this line to enable modal window. If you are getting other errors like what u mention, Please check version of your bootstrap js and jquery  files.

Comment: I have the default version which I downloaded from official site of bootstrap, do you think the default version dont work and we should modify it?? I think I have mostly made some mistakes with the calling libraries rather than editing bootsrap.js

Comment: This will trigger the modal onload, I believe he wants to trigger the modal onclick, which is what the line `<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>` does. He is instantiating the script files the wrong way

Answer (score 2):

You've got all of your scripts and css files loaded inside a script tag - take out the script tag that wraps the rest.

Comment: Sorry levelnis i have done a mistake, the scripts are outside the script tags actually and yet not working, btw i have to edit my question, I mean to say inside head tag

Answer (score 2):

In `wrapper_mod.css` add a css property

this worked in my case

```
myModal.in{
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before posting my complete solution i would like to know , have you initialized your modal before loading it.
Initialization:-

```
$(function(){
$('#myModal').modal({
   show:true,
   backdrop:'static'
});
 //now on button click
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the CDN route, the undermentioned should suffice:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If not using a CDN, be sure to include ***bootstrap.js, modal.js and popper.js*** in your header

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to put the CSS file inside  tag!

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
<link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: I dont get what changes u made here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amrebel/f2bdu/

You should create a fiddle... it is easier to solve the problem... I still don't get what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

You're loading your scripts wrong (some are loaded like stylesheets, some don't have the closing script tag).

It should be :

```
    <!--STYLESHEETS-->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!--SCRIPTS - MAKE SURE THE PATH IS RIGHT FOR THE BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue; After long analyse i find the solution : Adding "style="display:none;" on div modal. I don't know why but when you load the page the modal is hidden, but if you inspect with firebug the modal recover the dropdown. After shown the modal and hidden it; the js add "style="display:none;" and dropdown works.

Answer (score 0):

Use below online Bootstrap library or [download from here](http://getbootstrap.com).

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and paste this link before `bootstrap.js` link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Because Bootstrap model not working with older JS editions ([can check here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/16158)).

And in Bootstrap model remove `hide` class from here `class="modal fade"`

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your bootstrap model is not working [ running but not not displaying
[ ANGULAR ] then

add jquery links to the model

Link for jquery : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/ [Go to JS and copy all the links and paste it in index.html]

Your bootstrap modal will work perfectly fine

Why your modal didn't work : Until and unless we add jquery our bootstrap modal will not work

Thanks & regards

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Add bs between elements. For example, change `data-dismiss` to `data-bs-dismiss`, `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`, `data-target` to `data-bs-target` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had moved the scripts into another .html file from my base thymeleaf template and didn't pull those back into the base file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
```

I also needed to do the above mentioned change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` etc.