# Bootsrap modal not showing

Tags: javascript, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I have a button in a navbar that when clicked should open a modal. I tried following the bootstrap docs and this question: [bootstrap modal not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142790/bootstrap-modal-not-working-at-all)

Nothing works so far, and the console doesn't show any errors.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Legion Analytics</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body class = "bg-light">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 text-center">Legion Analytics</span>
            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning my-2 my-sm-0" id='open-modal-btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-modal">Update DB</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="modal fade" id="update-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="turvo-upload">
                            <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
                                <label for="file">Upload new Turvo Data</label>
                                <input type="file" name="turvo-upload-file" class="form-control-file" id="excel-upload-file">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="submit_turvo" method="POST" style="margin-top: 30px">
                                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id = "db_spinner_table"></span>
                                        Submit File
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            {% include 'rate_analysis.html' %}
            {% include 'rate_engine.html' %}
        </div>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/plots.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do either of your alerts appear?

Comment: @j08691 none of them do

Comment: @j08691 the original JS is actually unrelated, sorry about that, the post has been updated

Comment: The code you posted works for me https://www.bootply.com/rN56Ctp295

Comment: I've just clear my cache and reloaded my local server and it still doesnt work for me, I'm using a Flask server with jinja 2 for context

Comment: @j08691 I've added the scripts I include in my head files

Comment: The website works as expected otherwise...

Comment: I did not see the code before you removed extra things from your post but where is your reference to jquery and the actual bootsrap js. Seems to be missing. Also you button placement inside a form will cause form submission in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High level glance at your code and here is what has been modified:

1. JQuery included
2. Bootstrap js script file included (you only had the css included)
3. Form element wrapping button changed to a div to prevent auto form submission

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Legion Analytics</title>
         <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body class = "bg-light">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 text-center">Legion Analytics</span>
                <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning my-2 my-sm-0" id='open-modal-btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-modal">Update DB</button>
                </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="modal fade" id="update-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="turvo-upload">
                                <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
                                    <label for="file">Upload Excel DAT File</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="turvo-upload-file" class="form-control-file" id="excel-upload-file">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="submit_turvo" method="POST" style="margin-top: 30px">
                                        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id = "db_spinner_table"></span>
                                            Submit File
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Still did not work for me, I've included all my code in index.html as it appears as though the issue must be with the structure of the doc rather than the modal code itself(?)

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides look in your code and tell me where you are including bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js ?

Comment: In my `<head>` tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>`

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides That is the CSS file. You need the CSS file AND the JS file. They are two separate things and both are required.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I've added the bootstrap.min.js and still no effect, even after reloading cache and assets.

Comment: Edit your code snippet above and let me see what you have now

Comment: Done, I also tried running your code as is and it still doesnt work, which is weird because it clearly works when you run it on something like the stackoverflow compilier

Comment: So order matters in your javascript file includes. bootstrap.js relies on jquery.js. 
@AdrianCoutsoftides SOOO your bootstrap.js include line should be under your jquery.js line. You should also do this for your popper.js line as it also has a dependency on jquery. Also a simple rule of thumb is that your js includes should be at the bottom of the page while css is in the head.

Comment: Yeah that solved it! wow been making websites for a few years now and never knew this!